# Separar models relacionado no SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, relacionamento, flask, model, sqlalchemy

Possuo um model de tabelas relacionandas:

**models/Base.py**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from src.config.database import db


class Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
```

**models/Model.py**

```
from .Base import Base 
from src.config.database import db


class Estado(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ESTADO'

    id = db.Column('EST_ID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sigla = db.Column('EST_SIGLA', db.String, nullable=False)
    desc = db.Column('EST_NOME', db.String, nullable=False)

    enderecos = db.relationship('Endereco', backref=db.backref('estado', lazy='joined'), uselist=False)
    cidades = db.relationship('Cidade', backref=db.backref('cidade', lazy='joined'), lazy='dynamic')


class Cidade(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CIDADE'

    id = db.Column('CID_ID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = db.Column('CID_NOME', db.String, nullable=False)
    est_id = db.Column('EST_ID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ESTADO.EST_ID'))

    enderecos = db.relationship('Endereco', backref=db.backref('cidade', lazy='joined'), uselist=False)


class Endereco(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ENDERECO'

    id = db.Column('END_ID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cep = db.Column('END_CEP', db.String, nullable=False)
    bairro = db.Column('END_BAIRRO', db.String, nullable=False)
    numero = db.Column('END_NUMERO', db.String, nullable=False)
    complemento = db.Column('END_COMPLEMENTO', db.String, nullable=False)

    est_id = db.Column('EST_ID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ESTADO.EST_ID'))
    cid_id = db.Column('CID_ID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('CIDADE.CID_ID'))
```

Gostaria de separar o model por arquivos, tenho o arquivo **models/Model.py** e queria separar as classes em **models/Endereco.py, models/Estado.py e models/Cidade.py**. Porém quando separo, ele sempre dá erro avisando que a classe não existe do relacionamento. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Ou o correto seria manter no mesmo arquivo?

Comment: O qu acotnce se no arquivo `models.__init__.py` você importar os arquivos com os modelos na ordem desejada: `from ..models import base, estado, cidade, endereco`   (também - evite deixar os arquivos com a primeira letra em maiúscula - pode dar problemas com algumas ferramentas - deixe os nomes dos arquivos sempre em minúsculas)

Comment: o problema que acho que vou ter ao fazer isso, é que seria muitas classes para a importação manual, tenho mais de 50 tabelas, iria ter que importar um a um no dentro do __init__.py ? ou tem outra alternativa?

Comment: se vocẽ nao acha muito ter 50 arquivos - não é muito importar uma por uma. :-)  Em Python é completamente desnecessário ter u arqiuvo pra cada classe - ainda mais quando algumas vão ter poucas linhas e vão aparecer apenas como relacionamentos dentro de uma outra única classe. Mas vereifiquei aqui - sim, o problema é importar os módulos - não precisa ser na ordem certa - confira esta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31091883/108205